# Can we pass different credentials for SecretManagerTemplate in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-secret-manager, gcp-secret-manager

Is there a way to pass different credentials to SecretManagerTemplate (from spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager)?.

I've been searching ways of configuring different credentials for SecretManagerTemplate, but i've found nothing so far.

This is the dependency i'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is the example from Spring that i've been using:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/main/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-secretmanager-sample/src/main/java/com/example/SecretManagerWebController.java